# How to leverage geocoder distance function within SQL query through an association

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, distance, rails-geocoder

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to implement the SQL query where I can show the closest results (by calculated distance) first and paginate through them.

```
Class Location
   belongs_to :student
   geocoded_by :address
end


Class Student
   has_one :location
   has_one :school
end


Class School
   belongs_to :student
end
```

now within SQL, I want to have a query that can go through the association Student.joins(:location) and find me the closest student from the perspective of the student who is searching. This is after specifying a specific school (so a subset of the overall Students)

For example, Joe goes to LSU and wants to be shown a list of the closest students that also go to LSU. But the distance is based on Joe's location so this will be different if Bob runs the same query.

So I know geocoder provides something like Location.nearbys(10) but what I'd really like to do is say

```
joe = Student.find("Joe")

closest_lsu_stdents_to_joe = Student.where("school = LSU").order(distance_to(joe)).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

So I don't want to limit the search to a specified radius like nearbys does. I just want the database to calculate the distance between Joe and all the other students at LSU and return the closest ones first. And then Joe can go through all the results via the pagination.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using MySQL but open to other solutions.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I found this post: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/188293 - basically a sub-select performs some operations to calculate a distance field and then you can simply order by that field.  Is this kind of what you were after?

Comment: This might also help - a way to optimise the distance calculation by culling records beyond a certain bounding box: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,91048,119426#msg-119426

Comment: @AlexParker Thanks for the quick reply. I've seen the code snippets you referenced and I think that may be the route that I go with (it seems to be the easiest). There seem to be a couple other alternatives like stored procedures in mysql or switching to use a geospatial database like postgres w/ postgis. I was sort of hoping that the rails geocoder gem could handle this sort of query though. Doesn't seem too complex, but I could be wrong.

Comment: While I am fairly experienced with databases and a number of platforms and frameworks, RoR is outside of my field of specialization so I can't speak for anything rails-specific.  I am just starting on a project now with fairly heavy geolocation-based data, and switching to pg has been considered too.  Anyway I hope you find an answer soon, I'd be interested to see how this turns out.